# Passing arbitrary number of parameter to a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to write a javascript function that works something like this...

```
f([["a"]], function(e){alert(e);});
// results in alert("a");

f([["a"], ["b"]], function(e1,e2){alert(e1 + ":" + e2);});
//results in alert("a:b");

f([["a", "b"], ["c"]], function(e1,e2){alert(e1 + ":" + e2);});
//results in alert("a:c");alert("b:c");
```

I can think of a recursive solution for the looping, but how do I send a "unknown" number of variables to a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put all your arguments into an array (lets call it `foo`), you can call a function `fn` with those arguments by using the `apply`-function.

```
fn.apply(null, foo)
```

The first argument (`null` in this case) is whatever you want `this` to be inside of the called function. `null` will probably work for you.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://www.openjs.com/articles/optional_function_arguments.php), you can access any/all arguments using the `arguments` variable:

```
function f() {
    for( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
         //do something with arguments[i]
    }
}
```

[EDIT]

Now that I understand what you're trying to do, here's a (dirty) way to do it:

Seriously, don't do it this way.  It's horrible.  Puppies will die.

```
function f(arr, fn) {
    var s = "fn(";
    for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        //you can implement your recursive code here if you like; I'm just doing the base cases
        s += arr[i];
        if(i+1 < arr.length) {
            s += ",";
        }
    }
    s += ");";
    eval(s);
}
```

And for a cleaner way:

```
function f(arr, fn) {
    fn.apply(this, arr);
}
```

Comment: f() has fixed arguments. a array of arrays and a function - I need to send a unknown number of arguments to the anonymous alert function

Comment: @mncl Ah, I misunderstood.  So will the anon function always take the same number of arguments as the length of the array?

Comment: Yes. The alert function will do this arguments looping, if needed. But how do I pass the variables? That's the question.

Comment: @mncl What I meant was, if you pass `f` a three-element array, will the anonymous function take three arguments?  Is it required to take the same number of arguments as are in the length of the array?  If not (if the anonymous function can just take a random number of arguments), there's no viable way to do this.

Comment: It wants 3 then yes. But replace it with your
    for( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
         //do something with arguments[i]
    }
and it makes more sense for unknown size arrays.

Comment: @mncl I understand what you are looking for now.  See if my new answer helps (it's really ugly, but at least it doesn't require `eval`)

Comment: fn is not defined @ var callFunc = new Function(s);
I'm not familiar with how the Function object works, but it seems fn is out of scope.

Comment: Oh my god, the horror! Constructing a function-call with a string and evaluating it! But no, seriously, you should use the `apply`-function for that part.

Comment: @Jakob I agree, very horrendous.  I was trying to find `apply`, but hadn't come upon it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Within the function you can use the variable `arguments` to see what was passed. IE

```
function blah() {
   console.log(arguments);
}

blah(1, 2); // [1, 2]
blah([1, 2], [3]); // [[1,2], [3]]
blah(1, [2, 3], "string"); // [1, [2, 3], "string"]
```

Comment: The question is the exact opposite, I think.. if not can you write up how F would look?

Comment: You were asking how to get unknown variables. The answer is the arguments variable. I'm not sure what else you're asking for.

Comment: Im asking how to POST unknown variables - f() wants to CALL a function with the array size number of arguments. Not read unknow number of arguments.

Comment: So call the function with the array size number of arguments? I'm still not following your lead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) pseudo-array available within the function to get the arguments passed in without declaring them explicitly (i,e. regardless of whether you define an argument for a function, you can access everything passed in to the function via the `arguments` implicit variable within that function).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#Using_the_arguments_object) variable that each function has to go through all the passed in arguments.

```
function myConcat(separator) {  
   var result = ""; // initialize list  
   // iterate through arguments  
   for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {  
      result += arguments[i] + separator;  
   }  
   return result;  
}
```

See [this](http://www.openjs.com/articles/optional_function_arguments.php) article for a discussion of variable number of arguments.

Comment: Hm, we both found the same article!  Must be a good resource.