# JavaScript arbitrary function

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing arbitrary number of parameter to a function in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564076/passing-arbitrary-number-of-parameter-to-a-function-in-javascript)

How to create an arbitrary function in JavaScript? You know, like Math.min(x1,x2...xn). It can have infinite arguments. I tried to make it like this:

```
function arbfun(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,x16,x17,x18,x19,x20){...}
```

Thats not realy infinite is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the variable [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) from within the function:

```
function foo() {
  alert("Called with " + arguments.length + " arguments!");

  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    alert(arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/qWzme/)**.